# ошибка ClassNotFoundException(Maven, Java Servlets)

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

Проблема:
Приложение состоит из модулей: core, desktop и web. Всё собирается через maven. В модуле core заложено все общение с базой данных, desktop и web - используют core.  В core я использую connection pool c3p0. 
При пробном запуске обращения к бд из класса, находящегося в core, все проходит нормально, программа завершается с кодом 0. Но при попытке обращения из сервлета в web-модуле вылетает ошибка ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver. Инициализация пула соединений с заполнением данных проходит раньше вызова метода, который вызовет getConnection(), при чем проходит успешно(то есть core виден из web модуля и сам драйвер бд уже был найден при настройке c3p0).
Ниже pom файлы модулей. core:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>kvatra</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>jtree-killer</artifactId>
        <groupId>kvatra</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0-oracle-thin-extras</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

и web :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>jtree-killer</artifactId>
        <groupId>kvatra</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>kvatra</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>kvatra</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <compress>true</compress>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Необходимо больше информации - желательно ссылка на github c приложением.

Comment: Как вариант не прошла инциализация доайвера перед вызовом лоадера, пробуйте решить проблему Class.forName(...).newInstance()

Comment: @bsuart ссылка на git: https://github.com/kvatra/JTreeKiller/tree/web

Comment: посмотри тут : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903481/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-postgresql-driver-android    мне вообще кажется, нужно удалить скомпилированные файлы и заново скомпилировать проект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глеб,

Вы явно пытаетесь в коде установить драйвер класса: `cpds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");`, класса которого в Вашем classpath нет. Данный класс можно найти в официальной [PostgreSQL JDBC 4.2 Driver, 42.1.4](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.4.jar) jar, которую можно скачать и положить в папку `lib` вашего application сервера. Либо добавить ее в зависимости:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Как только Вы это сделаете Ваш код начнет пытаться присоединиться к Вашей БД. В моем случае я не стал поднимать PostgreSQL, но уже из кода ошибки понятно, что сервлет знает как и пытается подключиться к серверу:

```
Aug 26, 2017 1:35:54 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Надеюсь это поможет Вам в решении Вашей проблемы.

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо. Ранее добавялял такую зависимость :

Comment: Добавлял другую зависимость с драйвером и все равно вылетало         `<dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102.jdbc41</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: @GlebTuchinnscky Последнее не выглядит как что-то официальное =). Я предпочитаю и советую использовать только официальный софт, зависимости и так далее. Рад, что Вы теперь можете двигаться дальше. Удачи.